# Cannot Install npm on Mac 10.6.4 Strange Errors

Tags: installation, npm, juggernaut

```
MacPro:macpro fred$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3927  100  3927    0     0    958      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--  1038
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.0.22.tgz

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/utils/read-json.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/bin/read-package-json.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
0.2.5

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/utils/read-json.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/bin/read-package-json.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/utils/read-json.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/bin/read-package-json.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
! [ -d .git ] || git submodule update --init --recursive
node cli.js cache clean

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/utils/ini.js:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/config.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
make: *** [uninstall] Error 1

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/utils/ini.js:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/config.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)

node.js:63
    throw e;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at loadModule (node.js:275:15)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/utils/ini.js:31:10)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
    at Module._loadScriptSync (node.js:469:10)
    at Module.loadSync (node.js:338:12)
    at loadModule (node.js:283:14)
    at require (node.js:411:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/Da/DabGxbDzFA8Fcw2FWL3FpE+++TI/-Tmp-/npm.11529/package/lib/config.js:10:11)
    at Module._compile (node.js:462:23)
It failed
MacPro:macpro fred$
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Install the latest `node.js` and try to install `npm` now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't install npm directly.

npm has been [bundled with node since 0.6.3](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/ChangeLog#L1478).

If you install the latest node.js from http://nodejs.org/ you'll get npm aswell.